# How to prevent silverlight validation popup from appearing half off the screen

Tags: silverlight, validation, popup

I have a silverlight 4 application which has some text boxes that are as wide as the page.

When there is a validation error, a popup is displayed when the user clicks in the control.

The problem is - it only shows the popup for these long text boxes to the left of the text box. It wont go above or below and so as a consequence, most of the popup is displayed out of the page so its chopped off.

I know that I can re-template the text box and try to adjust the popup myself, but before doing that I just wanted to check to see if someone knew of a simple property or something that I can use to prevent that from happening?

Cheers

Rod.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I guess I would try to solve this via a somewhat "intelligent" `AttachedProperty`.
Pseudo code ahead:

```
<TextBox ... my:PopupUtils.KeepPopupWithinScreen="True"/>
```

And the (pseudo c#) code:

```
public static class PopupUtils
{
    // remember: pseudo code, just to get the idea
    static AttachedProperty KeepPopupWithinScreen = type: bool, default: false,
        onChanged: HandleKeepPopupWithinScreenChanged;

    private static void HandleKeepPopupWithinScreenChanged(
        DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
         obj.Loaded += HandleTargetElementLoaded;
    }

    private staic void HandleTargetElementLoaded(object sender, ...)
    {
        var popup = VisualTreeHelper.GetDecendantOfType<Popup>(sender);
        if ( popup != null )
        {
            var offsetController = new OffsetController();
            offsetController.SetBinding(ObservedOffsetProperty,
                new Binding("HorizontalOffset"){Source=popup});
            offsetController.ControlledTarget = popup;
            //now to prevent garbageCollection...
            SetAttachedOffsetController(popup,offsetController);
        }
    }

    public static AttachedProperty AttachedOffsetController = type:OffsetController;

}
```

I do this sometimes, so this pattern is actually working quite nicely. Maybe it feels a bit "unnatural" at first.

Comment: Hi Martin and Thanks.Will code this up and give it a go - Much appreciated. Will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Just letting you know of the solution I used to this problem.

It was another StackOverflow question which I have lost the reference to so I do apologise for not referencing it properly, but the problem is caused by the Text Box and other control styles having a fixed position of to the side of the control when displaying the validation message.

I simply had to create a copy of the style and have the popup appear at the top of the controls instead of beside it.

Problem Solved.

Cheers

Rod.